# Java Socket Read Input Twice

Tags: java, sockets

I have a situation with a Java Socket Input reader.
I am trying to develop an URCAP for Universal Robots and for this I need to use JAVA.

The situation is as follow:
I connect to the Dashboard server through a socket on IP 127.0.0.1, and port 29999.
After that the server send me a message "Connected: Universal Robots Dashboard Server".
The next step I send the command "play".
Here starts the problem. If I leave it like this everything works.
If I want to read the reply from the server which is "Starting program" then everything is blocked.

I have tried the following:

-read straight from the input stream-no solution

-read from an buffered reader- no solution

-read into an byte array with an while loop-no solution

I have tried all of the solution presented here and again no solution for my case.
I have tried even copying some code from the Socket Test application and again no solution.
This is strange because as mentioned the Socket Test app is working with no issues.

Below is the link from the URCAP documentation:

https://www.universal-robots.com/articles/ur/dashboard-server-cb-series-port-29999/

I do not see any reason to post all the trials code because I have tried everything.
Below is the last variant of code maybe someone has an idea where I try to read from 2 different buffered readers. The numbers 1,2,3 are there just so I can see in the terminal where the code blocks.

In conclusion the question is: How I can read from a JAVA socket 2 times?
Thank you in advance!

```
public void sendPlay()  {
                        
    try {
        // Create a new Socket Client
        Socket sc = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 29999);
        
        if (sc.isConnected()) {
            
            InputStream is = sc.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            String data = "";
            int s = in.read();
            
               
            data += ""+(char)s;
            int len = in.available();
            System.out.println("Len got : "+len);
            if(len > 0) {
                byte[] byteData = new byte[len];
                in.read(byteData);
                data += new String(byteData);
            }
            
            System.out.println(data);
            System.out.println("1");
            
            
            
            // Create stream for data
            DataOutputStream out;
            out = new DataOutputStream(sc.getOutputStream());
            String command = new String();

            command = "play"+"\n";
            // Send command
            out.write(command.getBytes("US-ASCII"));
            out.flush();
            System.out.println("2");
            
            
            InputStream is1 = sc.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream in1 = new BufferedInputStream(is1);
            String data1 = "";
            int s1 = in1.read();
            
               
            data1 += ""+(char)s1;
            int len1 = in1.available();
            System.out.println("Len got : "+len1);
            if(len1 > 0) {
                byte[] byteData1 = new byte[len1];
                in.read(byteData1);
                data1 += new String(byteData1);
            }
            
            System.out.println(data1);
            
        
            System.out.println("3");
            

            // Perform housekeeping
            out.close();
            sc.close();
        }
        sc.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: It looks like a basic text based protocol, so `BufferedReader` and `PrintWriter` are all you need for reading and writing lines. Shortens that to 6-7 lines or so. Then you just call `readLine()` for reading and `println()` for writing. If the protocol is message-reply style, then you'll manage with a single thread.

Comment: Hi pop.  Have you tried reusing your input stream variable from the first section of your code?

Comment: 1. You are losing data in all the `BufferedInputStreams`. Use the same one for the life of the socket. 2. Get rid of the `available()` test and just block in `read()`. 3. `isConnected()` cannot possibly be false at the point you are testing it. A lot of pointless code here. Don't write pointless code. 4. If sending lines is correct you should also be reading lines, with `BufferedReader.readLine()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to the issue of reading the from the socket multiple times with a Swing GUI.

```
public void sendPlay() {
Thread appThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                RobotTester robot = new RobotTester("127.0.0.1", 29999);
                    System.out.println("Connected to robot.");
                    robot.nextInput();               //Read and print robot's welcome message
                    robot.writeCommand("play");      //Send command
                    String resp = robot.nextInput(); //Read result
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Finished on " + Thread.currentThread());
        }
    };
    appThread.start();}
```

It seems that the background socket reading needs to be on a separate thread. This was causing the entire robot to be blocked. The idea was from an forum. It was not mine, but hey, it works.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are opening several input streams to the same socket for reading commands.

You should open one `InputStream` for reading, one `OutputStream` for writing, and keep them both open till the end of the connection to your robot.

Then you can wrap those streams into helper classes for your text-line based protocol like `Scanner` and `PrintWriter`.

Sample program to put you on track (can't test with your hardware so it might need little tweaks to work):

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RobotTester implements AutoCloseable {
    
    private Socket clientSocket;
    private Scanner inputReader;
    private PrintWriter outWriter;
    private int incounter;
    private int outcounter;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Program started. Connecting to robot");
        try (RobotTester robot = new RobotTester("127.0.0.1", 29999)) {
            System.out.println("Connected to robot.");
            robot.nextInput();               //Read and print robot's welcome message
            robot.writeCommand("play");      //Send command
            String resp = robot.nextInput(); //Read result
            if (resp.toLowerCase().startsWith("fail")) {
                throw new Exception("Play command failed: " + resp);
            }
            System.out.println("Command succeeded!");
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public RobotTester(String host, int port) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        clientSocket = new Socket(host, port);
        inputReader = new Scanner(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        outWriter = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    }

    public String nextInput() {
        String mess = inputReader.nextLine();
        System.out.println("< " + (++incounter) + ": " + mess);
        return mess;
    }

    public void writeCommand(String command) {
        System.out.println("> " + (++outcounter) + ": " + command);
        outWriter.print(command);
        outWriter.print('\n');
        outWriter.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        if (inputReader != null) {
            inputReader.close();
            inputReader = null;
        }
        if (outWriter != null) {
            outWriter.close();
            outWriter = null;
        }
        if (clientSocket != null) {
            clientSocket.close();
            clientSocket = null;
        }
    }

}
```

In addition, you're using 127.0.0.1 as server IP address, which is the loopback on your PC. Unless the interface to your robot works in a very peculiar way, the actual IP you should use is probably not this one.

I'm refering to this part of documentation here:

> Setup a static IP-address and subnet mask on PC, so it matches the
> robot, e.g.:
>
> PC: IP-addr: 192.168.3.10 Robot: IP-addr: 192.168.3.3
>
> Subnet: 255.255.255.0 Subnet: 255.255.255.0

***Edit***
If you've got more commands to put, use it like this:

```java
//Inside your actual main class
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Program started. Connecting to robot");
        try (RobotTester robot = new RobotTester("127.0.0.1", 29999)) {

            System.out.println("Connected to robot.");
            robot.nextInput();               //Read and print robot's welcome message

            robot.writeCommand("play");      //Send command
            String resp = robot.nextInput(); //Read result
            if (resp.toLowerCase().startsWith("fail")) {
                throw new Exception("Play command failed: " + resp);
            }
            System.out.println("Command succeeded!");

            robot.writeCommand("command1");  //Send command
            resp = robot.nextInput();        //Read result
            //Process result for command1

            robot.writeCommand("command2");  //Send command
            resp = robot.nextInput();        //Read result
            //Process result for command2

            //...

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It wouldn't matter how peculiar the robot was, it could never accept a connection as 127.0.0.1 from another host, by definition.

Comment: I meant it could be made through a local server program that in turn connects to the robot and transmits commands

Comment: Hi @pop. If it's simply a matter of reading/writing lines to the socket, then there's no reason. Just keep one and only one `RobotTester`, and alternate calling `writeCommand` -> `nextInput`.

Comment: Unless you've got several lines of response to read from the robot at once, in which case you may have to arrange for reading all of them before sending the next command

Comment: Hello @julien.giband, thank you very much for your input. I have tried your class and it works perfectly. The issue is that if I implement some methods from your class I have the same issue, I can read the first response and after I send the command the entire software is blocked. Also regarding the IP the you are also right there is a local server. So if you have any idea why I cannot call some methods please tell me. I already tried creating and object from your class and work with that also I have tried making them static and called them but still did not work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually the class is not required. It's just here to ease the process of closing the open resources. The methods also help outputting exchanges to the console but are not essential to the program. The idea here is : create a new RobotTester, use it for writing/reading as many times as required, when your program is done close it

Comment: Also I've left the main method inside RobotTester for convenience, but this one belongs in another class in a real-world program. It has no use for the class itself

Comment: Hello @julien.giband So what I have found is that this methods are working fine in Main method. When I am calling them in public void actionPerformed (from a button) event in a dialog window they do not work. It seems that I do not grasp the idea of object oriented program. I am doing something wrong but I do not understand what. If I copy paste the main method it runs without any problem. I am still trying to see what I can do.

Comment: Just remember one thing and it shall work: one input/output stream per open socket. So long as you commit to that, no matter how your code is arranged

Comment: I have just one socket. One question, what is the difference between a function which is called by the Main, and the same function which is called by a button or something else? Because I see that there is the issue.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing any code. The only thing that comes to my mind is that `main` is in the `static` scope while a button event handler is probably in your form's instance scope. I don't see how it's relevant here

Comment: You should design a minimal reproductible example and ask another question showing your code

Answer (score 0):

The latest update is that I have moved all the functions in the same Dialog and just called them straight from there, and is still not working.
I already double check there is just one stream and one writer and reader in the entire project.

```
 JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("START");
            btnNewButton_2.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            btnNewButton_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            
            try {
                RobotTester("127.0.0.1", 29999);
                nextInput();
                String command="play";
                writeCommand(command);
                nextInput();
            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            
            try {
                close();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            
            
        }       });


public void RobotTester(String host, int port) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
    clientSocket = new Socket(host, port);
    inputReader = new Scanner(clientSocket.getInputStream());
    outWriter = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
}

public String nextInput() {
    String mess = inputReader.nextLine();
    System.out.println("< " + (++incounter) + ": " + mess);
    return mess;
}

public void writeCommand(String command) {
    System.out.println("> " + (++outcounter) + ": " + command);
    outWriter.print(command);
    outWriter.print('\n');
    outWriter.flush();
}

public void close() throws Exception {
    if (inputReader != null) {
        inputReader.close();
        inputReader = null;
    }
    if (outWriter != null) {
        outWriter.close();
        outWriter = null;
    }
    if (clientSocket != null) {
        clientSocket.close();
        clientSocket = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't mean to dismiss you but there has been way too much discussion here already.  SO is not a forum. Obviously you need to aquire some basic knowledge about Java to take your project further. You should start with https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/index.htm . Make sure you understand what those things are : class, method, constructor, field, class variable, try with resources. Then ask questions if required on SO. Good luck man

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much for all the help. I will try to see if I find a solution. Have a lovely evening!